Can I reuse PT beams?
We took down a deck that was decades old. I was thinking of cleaning and reusing the 4x8 beams. They're filthy and the ends need to be trimmed, but seem ok otherwise. Any reason I should reconsider?


If not rotted, no reason you cannot reuse them.

If you do trim the ends (which looks like it is needed), be sure to apply some good protectant on the cut ends to better protect them from rot/insects. Copper naphthenate is fairly common and not hard to find.
